# Breakpoints don't fire on results returned from ResetPasswordAsync

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to figure out why `UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync` sometimes returns an object that evaluates to a fail.  So I tried to put breakpoints on line 1876 and 1877 in the image below:

[image]

But the breakpoints never stop on 1876 or 1877.  It only stops on 1875 and 1881.

Why wont it stop on 1876 or 1877?  How else do I determine why `result.Succeeded === false` ?

---

**OTHER INFO**
In the image above, the code comes from a file called `CustomerController.cs` and is part of a method called

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("ResetPassword")]
public async Task<object> ResetPassword([FromBody]CustomerViewModel model) {
   // .. some other code
   // insert the image above
}
```

This method serves as an API end point for a user to reset their password.  The `model.CodeResetPassword` was generated further upstream in the user's reset password workflow from a function called `var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);`

Comment: What are you debugging, decompiled sources? Please read [ask] and paint us the entire picture, we can't look at your screen.

Comment: I added some more details to the question

Comment: So it's your code at least. Are you debugging a Debug or a Release build? Are you debugging the version that you are running? And so on. Please show in your question that you've searched the web for "visual studio c# not hitting breakpoint" and tried to apply some of the suggestions you've read.

Comment: thanks VIsual studio  was still set on on release mode.  Changing to debug mode allowed the remaining breakpoints to activate